# openssl only works on certain ports

Tags: ssl, gmail-imap

I'm trying to connect to gmail servers using imap from my web server which has ssl on port 443. It returns with a "can't connect" error but goes through after a long wait (not sure how).
I've been testing with openssl and have determined the problem is the port. 
On my mail server I am able to run the following with no problems.

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993
```

When I run it on my web server I get connection refused. If I change it to

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:443
```

it works fine since my ssl cert is set up on port 443.

Is there anyway I can connect on port 993?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter which ports are open to the outside on the system you are running an SSL client. It only matters what ports are open from the inside, i.e. where you can connect to.

In your case it looks like that there is a firewall which allows incoming connections on port 443 to your server, allows outgoing connection to some external system port 443 from your server but restricts access to external systems port 993 from your server. This means you can reach `https://imap.gmail.com` (port 443) but not `imaps://imap.gmail.com` (port 993) from the server.

If you have access to the firewall and can change its rules then you can add the appropriate rule/exception. If you don't have such access you have to ask the administrators responsible for the systems to do this. If they don't want to do this (for security reasons) you will not get direct access from the server to imap.gmail.com port 993.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. I do have access to the firewall and have opened the outgoing port. When I run  `openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:993 -dtls1 -debug ` I get  `write:errno=111
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 115 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
  `

Comment: *"SSL handshake has read 0 bytes"* - this means that the TCP connection now succeeds (did not before) but that either the server or (more likely) some deep inspection middlebox (firewall) did not like the access and blocked it.